# Set position in customized list field in Blackberry?

Tags: java, blackberry

I want three list field items to be displayed, from bottom to top.  I am able to display three list field items, but they display from top to bottom.  I have tried setting the position, but it isn't working.

```
import java.util.Vector;


import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Display;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.ContextMenu;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.DrawStyle;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Font;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Manager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.MenuItem;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.BitmapField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ListField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ListFieldCallback;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.NullField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.FullScreen;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;
import net.rim.device.api.util.Arrays;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ListField;

/**
 * @author Jason Emerick
 */
public class TaskListField extends UiApplication 
{
        //statics ------------------------------------------------------------------
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            TaskListField theApp = new TaskListField();
            theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
        }
        public TaskListField()
        {
            pushScreen(new TaskList());
        }

}
/*class List extends FullScreen {
    TaskList tl;
    List(){
     super();
    TaskList tl=new TaskList();
    }
}*/
class TaskList extends MainScreen implements ListFieldCallback {
     private Vector rows;
     private Bitmap p1;
     private Bitmap p2;
     private Bitmap p3;
     String Task;
     ListField listnew=new ListField();
     public TaskList() {
      super();
      listnew.setRowHeight(50);
      //setEmptyString("Hooray, no tasks here!", DrawStyle.HCENTER);
      listnew.setCallback(this);

      p1 = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("1.png");
      p2 = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("2.png");
      p3 = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("3.png");

      rows = new Vector();

      for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
       TableRowManager row = new TableRowManager();
       if (x== 0) {
            Task="On Air Now";
        }
       if (x== 1) {
            Task="Music Channel";
        }
       if (x==2) {
            Task="News Channel";
        }
       // SET THE PRIORITY BITMAP FIELD
       // if high priority, display p1 bitmap
       if (x % 2 == 0) {
        row.add(new BitmapField(p1));

       }

       // if priority is 2, set p2 bitmap
       else if (x % 3 == 0) {
        row.add(new BitmapField(p2));

       }
       // if priority is 3, set p3 bitmap
       else {
        row.add(new BitmapField(p3));

       }

       // SET THE TASK NAME LABELFIELD
       // if overdue, bold/underline
       LabelField task = new LabelField(Task,
         DrawStyle.ELLIPSIS);

       // if due today, bold
       if (x % 2 == 0) {
        task.setFont(Font.getDefault().derive(
          Font.BOLD));

       } else {
        task.setFont(Font.getDefault().derive(Font.BOLD));

       }

       row.add(task);

       LabelField task1 = new LabelField("Now Playing" + String.valueOf(x),
                 DrawStyle.ELLIPSIS);

               // if due today, bold
              /* if (x % 2 == 0) {
                task.setFont(Font.getDefault().derive(
                  Font.BOLD));

               } else {
                task.setFont(Font.getDefault().derive(Font.BOLD));

               }*/
               Font myFont = Font.getDefault().derive(Font.PLAIN, 12);
               task1.setFont(myFont);

               row.add(task1);


       // SET THE DUE DATE/TIME
      row.add(new LabelField("",
         DrawStyle.ELLIPSIS | LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH
           | DrawStyle.RIGHT) {
        protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
         graphics.setColor(0x00878787);
         super.paint(graphics);
        }
       });
       rows.addElement(row);
      }

      listnew.setSize(rows.size());
      this.add(listnew);
     }

     // ListFieldCallback Implementation
     public void drawListRow(ListField listField, Graphics g, int index, int y,
       int width) {
      //TaskList list =(TaskListField) listnew;
    TableRowManager rowManager = (TableRowManager)rows
        .elementAt(index);
      rowManager.drawRow(g, 0, y, width, listnew.getRowHeight());
     }

     private class TableRowManager extends Manager {
      public TableRowManager() {
       super(0);
      }

      // Causes the fields within this row manager to be layed out then
      // painted.
      public void drawRow(Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
       // Arrange the cell fields within this row manager.
       layout(0, 1);

       // Place this row manager within its enclosing list.
       setPosition(x,y);

       // Apply a translating/clipping transformation to the graphics
       // context so that this row paints in the right area.
      g.pushRegion(getExtent());

       // Paint this manager's controlled fields.
       subpaint(g);

       g.setColor(0x00CACACA);
       g.drawLine(0, 0, getPreferredWidth(), 0);

       // Restore the graphics context.
       g.popContext();
      }

      // Arrages this manager's controlled fields from left to right within
      // the enclosing table's columns.
      protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
       // set the size and position of each field.
       int fontHeight = Font.getDefault().getHeight();
       int preferredWidth = getPreferredWidth();

       // start with the Bitmap Field of the priority icon
      /* Field field = getField(0);
       layoutChild(field, 0, 0);
       setPositionChild(field, 150, 300);*/

       // set the task name label field
    /*   field = getField(1);
       layoutChild(field, preferredWidth - 16, fontHeight + 1);
       setPositionChild(field, 34, 3);

       // set the list name label field
       field = getField(2);
       layoutChild(field, 150, fontHeight + 1);
       setPositionChild(field, 34, fontHeight + 6);*/

       // set the due time name label field
/*     field = getField(3);
       layoutChild(field, 150, fontHeight + 1);
       setPositionChild(field,4,340);*/

    /* layoutChild(listnew, preferredWidth, fontHeight);
        setPositionChild(listnew, 3, 396);*/
      setExtent(360, 480);

      }

      // The preferred width of a row is defined by the list renderer.
      public int getPreferredWidth() {
       return getWidth();
      }

      // The preferred height of a row is the "row height" as defined in the
      // enclosing list.
      public int getPreferredHeight() {
       return listnew.getRowHeight();
      }
     }

     public Object get(ListField listField, int index) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return null;
     }

     public int getPreferredWidth(ListField listField) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return 0;
     }

     public int indexOfList(ListField listField, String prefix, int start) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return 0;
     }

    }
```

What do I need to fix to make it work as I want?

Comment: The code you posted is not all formatted correctly.  Unrelated to your problem: many of your variable names are not descriptive and therefore make your code hard for anyone to read it.  Lastly, I don't understand your question. Is it about the order of three lists or the order of a list with 3 items?

Comment: i have a list field with three list items,i am able to display it but its displaying those three list items from top to bottom,i need to display it from bottom to top

Comment: I still don't understand your question. Do you want to change the initial focus so that it is on the last item instead of the first?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you want to know how to change the focus to item 3 in your listfield

So the answer is:

```
listnew.setSelectedIndex(2);
```

Comment: Thank you.How do i display image from a url dynamically